# How to set different MySQL database for testing?

Tags: laravel

I have installed a fresh Laravel project. I tried to set different database for PHPUnit testing, by adding "DB_DATABASE" And adding "use DatabaseMigrations" trait inside the test..

```xml
<server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
<server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
<server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
<server name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="array"/>
<server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
<server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
<server name="DB_DATABASE" value="test_homestead" />
```

But I am getting this error:

```
1) Tests\Feature\ViewArticleTest::user_can_view_an_article
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'test_homestead' (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')`
```

Comment: you can remove `<server name="DB_DATABASE" value="test_homestead" />` it will pick the value from the `.env` file

Comment: Or alternatively you can set `<server name="DB_DATABASE" value="sqlite" />`

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that your `test_homestead` isn't available in your MySQL.

You should create a database by perform `CREATE DATABASE test_homestead;` in MySQL.

Or

Change the `value` in `<server name="DB_DATABASE" value="test_homestead" />` to your desirable existing database name.